Is finite-time explosion possible for a vector field $X:I\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $X(s,t) = (1, f(s,t))$?
Let $I=(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Consider a vector field $X$ on $I\times \mathbb{R}$ of the form $$X(s,t)=(1,f(s,t)),$$
for some continuous function $f:I\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.
Consider $s_0\in I$ and let $\alpha:I_0\to I\times \mathbb{R}$ be the maximal integral curve of $X$ starting at $(s_0,0)$, i.e. $\alpha$ satisfies
$$\alpha'(s) = X(\alpha(s))\quad \text{and} \quad \alpha(s_0) = (s_0,0),$$
and if $\tilde{\alpha}:I_1\to I\times \mathbb{R}$ is another such solution, then $I_1\subset I_0$.

Question. Can we claim that $I_0=I$?

What I've tried: We know that maximal solutions must satisfy the following. Denoting $I_0=(\omega_-,\omega_+)$, then if $s\to \omega_{\pm}$ we must have that $\alpha(s)\to \partial \Omega$, where $\Omega= I\times \mathbb{R}$. Is that right? Please, tell me if not.
Since the first coordinate of $X$ is constant equal to $1$ and $\alpha(s_0)=(s_0,0)$, we know $\alpha$ must have the form $\alpha(s)=(s,y(s))$, for some function $y:I_0\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $y'(s)= f(s,y(s))$.
If $I_0\subsetneq I$, then we must have $\omega_+<b$ or $a<\omega_-$. Suppose for example $\omega_+<b$. The condition $\alpha \to \partial \Omega$ then imposes that $y(s)\to \pm \infty$, i.e. we have a finite-time explosion like solution. However, I kinda can't imagine such an example, because $\omega_+$ is an interior point of $I$ in that case, right? And therefore $X$ is defined on points $(\omega_+,t)$, with $t\in \mathbb{R}$. But for this explosion like behavior, intuition says me that, "by continuity", such vectors $X(\omega_+,t)$ should be vertical. But that's not possible since the first coordinate of $X$ is constant equal to $1$.
I can't neither give a precise proof that we actually have $I_0=I$ nor give a counterexample of an $X$ such that $I_0\subsetneq I$.

I do not get why the classical counterexample does not work. Consider for example $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(t,y)=1+y^2$.

@MatteoDR It works! Thank you so much.

@MatteoDR Sorry to bother again, but what conditions on $f$ should we ask in order to avoid such behavior? I see  that $f$ bounded is enough, but that sounds a bit too strong. Can we ask some weaker condition? Lipschitz on some of the variables, or whatever?

There are several sufficent conditions to establish global existence of (maximal) solutions. The first that comes in my mind is the case of vector field with linear growth, i.e.
$$
|f(t,x)|\leq a(t) (|x|+1) ;;;\forall ,(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R^n}.
$$
with $a\in L^1_{loc}$ (if I remeber well). The proof is based on the ''comparison principle''.
